# Recode a variable according to key value on another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dplyr

I have two datasets, one where the key variable is unique on each row and another where the key variable repeats on a number of rows; like in this example data:

```
set.seed(300)    
data1 <- data.frame(key = LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 5 )], value = rnorm(5,1,1))
data2 <- data.frame(key = rep(LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 5 )], 2), value = rnorm(10,1,1))
```

I want a function to recode the `value` variable on `data1` according to the minimum value of the `value`variable on `data2`.

To do so, I've been trying to repeat it on each `key` value, like this:

```
data1$value[data1$key == "A"] <- min(range(data2$value[data2$key == "A"]))
data1$value[data1$key == "B"] <- min(range(data2$value[data2$key == "B"]))
data1$value[data1$key == "C"] <- min(range(data2$value[data2$key == "C"]))
data1$value[data1$key == "D"] <- min(range(data2$value[data2$key == "D"]))
data1$value[data1$key == "E"] <- min(range(data2$value[data2$key == "E"]))
```

I know there must be a bunch of different ways to accomplish this, but I haven't found the way (maybe using dplyr?) and I would like to avoid a for loop.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I don't want to `dplyr::summarise` a new dataframe; I need to keep the other variables present in `data1` (yes, originally there are more variables than I put on here).

Comment: So, the current value of `data1` doesn't matter, you just want the min by group for `data2` (and replace `data1` with that). Look at the [How to sum by group R-FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/903061) and replace `sum` with `min` in your favorite answer. With `dplyr`: `data1 <- data2 %>% group_by(key) %>% summarize(value = min(value))`. Or in base R `data1 <- aggregate(value ~ key, data2, min)`

Comment: If there are other columns of `data1` you need to keep, treat this as an intermediate step and follow it up with a join (`left_join` in `dplyr`. `merge()` in base).